# Compute $P[ \mu-1 \leq X \leq 2\mu]$ where $Var(x)=1/2$ and $E[X]= \mu$ and X is positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I want to compute  $P[  \mu-1 \leq X \leq 2\mu]$ where $Var(x)=1/2$ and $E[X]= \mu$ and X is positive.
I suspect that I must use some known enequality since I know nothing for the distirbution. The thing is that the two "endings" of the enequality $2\mu, \mu-1$ do not seem to connect .
I tried to write it as : $$P[\mu-2\sigma^2 \leq X \leq \mu /\sigma]$$
or
$$P[-1\leq X-\mu \leq \mu]$$
I never really used that X is positive..
Can you help ?

Comment: Those are not enough to determine this probability.

Comment: You can only bound below. You bound above 1 minus the probabiliy by  $P[|X-\mu| > \min(1,\mu)]$ and by Bienaymé - Tchebycheff inequality. Positivity of $X$ ensures that $\min(1,\mu)>0$.